# SIGABRT in binary read/write

Tags: c++, memory, serialization, io

I wrote a very small code snippet and have already gotten the following error:

`malloc: *** error for object 0x100100080: pointer being freed was not allocated`

Problem is, I have no idea what pointer the compiler's talking about. I pass a variable in by address to the read/write functions, but I never freed it as far as I know. Where's the error in my code? I ran it with Leaks and Zombies, but got nothing.

Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Bank
{
 private:
    string __name;

 public:
   Bank() 
   { 
      __name = ""; 
   }
   Bank(string name) 
   {
      __name = name; 
   }

    string getName() const { return __name; }
};


 int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    Bank bank("Bank of America");
    Bank bank2;

    cout << "Bank1: " << bank.getName() << endl; 
    string filename = bank.getName() + ".bank";

    ofstream fout(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
    if (fout.good())
      fout.write((char *)&bank, sizeof(bank));
    fout.close();

    ifstream fin(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
    if (fin.good())
      fin.read((char *)&bank2, sizeof(bank2));
    fin.close();

    cout << "Bank2: " << bank2.getName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use identifiers `__like_this` nor `_Like_this`, they're reserved to the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't read an object that contains a std::string (or anything that's not Plain Ol' Data) with fin.read()--

The object is read and written as a stream of bytes, but std:string contains a pointer to memory that is stored elsewhere and is not written with your fout.write() and is not initialized properly with your fin.read()

It is because it is not initialized properly with your fin.read() that you are getting the heap error; when the object goes out of scope, the destructor of the improperly initialized std::string is being called, and trying to free memory that it doesn't own.

You probably want to write a custom i/o method for your object and save or load it piece-by-piece.  For a shortcut to doing this, use the Boost serialization library.

Comment: You can't even reliably to this with PODs, except within the same executable.

Answer (score 1):

Because your Bank class contains a std::string, you can't read/write it as binary like you are thinking.  A std::string has internal pointers.  If you write it as binary, you are just going to be writing pointers and not the actual string contents.  Likewise, when you read the string, you are going to be reading a pointer.  In this case, you end up making both your bank and bank2 objects have strings which point to the same memory, so when that memory is freed it gets freed twice.

You'll need to have some other way of writing your bank data to a file.  In this case, a simple ASCII file with the bank name would be fine.

Comment: Later on however, it's going to have multiple fields such as a `vector<Account>` to store objects of type `Account` (to be defined later). A binary file would seem easier to work so that I can read the data as a whole and not parse it.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't anything built in to c++ that will let you do that easily.  There are libraries such as boost::serialization which try to make it easier, but you'll still have to make changes to your serialization code if you change your class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are doing, simply because `std::string` cannot be copied like that. Internally a `string` object allocates memory and a simple copy of the outer structure doesn't do what you expect.

You need to serialize this structure properly.

Comment: How do you properly serialize an object though? In a book I read, they had a `Bear` object which they wrote to/read from a binary file just like above.

Comment: For a POD (Plain-Old-Datatype) this is okay, however this structure includes elements which internally have dynamically allocated components, a bitwise copy (which is effectively what `write` does), does not understand that the `string` really stores the contents elsewhere in memory. Look at something like boost serialization and you'll see how to implement this strategy.

Comment: For a POD, it's only okay for temporary storage.  Recompile your program with different options, or a different version of the compiler, and you may not be able to read what you'd written earlier.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use underscores, please
2. Pass objects by reference: `Bank(string& name)`, please
3. This is evil: `fout.write((char *)&bank, sizeof(bank));`
4. You may want to write `<<` and `>>` ostream operators of your `Bank` class.

For example:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Bank& b);
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &out, const Bank& b);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with underscores and passing by value? And why is `fout.write()` _evil_?

Comment: first two are not evil :) just good practice. getting the address of Bank and casting to char won't work. If you want to get the string bytes, then write a GetBytes method that returns __name::c_str() which is a const pointer.

Comment: What if I make the `__name` field of type `char*`, would serialization work well then?

Comment: not if you write `(char *)&bank`, that is: getting the address of a Bank object is not as getting it's field's address (you may have more than one field). You have the option of declaring Bank::operator&() which I would discourage you to do.

Comment: but wouldn't it solve the problem of string having an internal pointer?

Comment: Or would a `char[]` be better?

Comment: The answer is already in this page, I don't think there's a need to give more answers, you may need to study the language a little more.

Comment: Second recommendation is evil, it should be `Bank(const string&)`.  And it's double underscores, as well as leading underscores, that are evil (they are reserved for the use of the compiler, you should never use them for your own identifiers), not underscores in general.

Answer (score 0):

Members functions write of ostream and read of istream are specifically designed to input and output binary data. If you do want to manipulate binary data, use the following:

```
ifstream fin(filename.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
size = fin.tellg();
memblock = new char [size];
fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);

if (fin.good()){
   fin.read(memblock, size);
   fin.close();
}
delete[] memblock;
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  Member functions `write` and `read` are designed to write pre-formatted text, and read raw text to be parsed outside of iostream.  There is no support for any binary format in the standard (probably because there is no one widely used binary format).